# Maintain alignment with scaled sibling without inverse-scaling

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have an element that requires the background to be scaled, without scaling the elements within the parent. I have achieved this by using a `pseudo` element to define the background, and then on `hover` I simply scale the `pseudo` element. So far, so good...

The problem is, I need some of the elements to stay inline with the scaled background, despite not scaling themselves. My original plan was to simply `translate` them, but I quickly realised that is not possible due to `scale` being based on multiples, and `translate` being based on percentage/pixels etc...

The obvious solution is to scrap `scale` and instead use margin to shrink the absolutely positioned `pseudo` element. However, my reservation with this is that it is bad practice to `transition` the margin value.

Can anybody think of a way in which I can use `scale`, and also maintain the alignment?

### Update

***I want to avoid inverse/reverse scaling at all costs as it renders badly in the browser in most cases. With that in mind, I don't think this is actually possible but will leave the question open in case anyone is aware of some CSS magic.***

See the following snippet as an example:

```css
.tile {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 40px;
}

.tile:hover:before {
  transform: scale(.9);
}

.tile:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.tile > .button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <div class="button">Align Me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try scaling `.tile` itself and reverse-scaling its children:

```css
.tile {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: #000;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.tile>* {
  color: white;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
}

.tile>.button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.tile:hover {
  transform: scale(.9);
}

.tile:hover>* {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <section>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>I have an element that requires the background to be scaled, without scaling the elements within the parent. I have achieved this by using a pseudo element to define the background, and then on hover I simply scale the pseudo element. So far, so good...
      The problem is, I need some of the elements to stay inline with the scaled background, despite not scaling themselves. My original plan was to simply translate them, but I quickly realised that is not possible due to scale being based on multiples,
      and translate being based on percentage/pixels etc... The obvious solution is to scrap scale and instead use margin to shrink the absolutely positioned pseudo element. However, my reservation with this is that it is bad practice to transition the
      margin value. Can anybody think of a way in which I can use scale, and also maintain the alignment?</p>
  </section>
  <div class="button">Align Me</div>
</div>
```

Another idea is animating `top` and `right` of `.button`:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 75%; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.tile {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.tile:hover:before {
  transform: scale(.9);
}

.tile:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.tile>.button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}

.tile:hover>.button {
  top: 5%;
  right: 5%
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <p>I have an element that requires the background to be scaled, without scaling the elements within the parent. I have achieved this by using a pseudo element to define the background, and then on hover I simply scale the pseudo element. So far, so good...
    The problem is, I need some of the elements to stay inline with the scaled background, despite not scaling themselves. My original plan was to simply translate them, but I quickly realised that is not possible due to scale being based on multiples,
    and translate being based on percentage/pixels etc... The obvious solution is to scrap scale and instead use margin to shrink the absolutely positioned pseudo element. However, my reservation with this is that it is bad practice to transition the
    margin value. Can anybody think of a way in which I can use scale, and also maintain the alignment?</p>

  <div class="button">Align Me</div>
</div>
```

The next idea is using a bit more complex code, but doing animation of `transform` property only:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 75%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.tile {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.tile:hover:before {
  transform: scale(.9);
}

.tile:before,
.tile>.button {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width:100%; height:100%;  
  background: #000;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.tile>.button {
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0 -100% -100% 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tile>.button div {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.tile>.button:before {
  content: '';
  flex: 1 0;
}

.tile:hover>.button {
  transform: translate3d(-5%, 5%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <p>I have an element that requires the background to be scaled, without scaling the elements within the parent. I have achieved this by using a pseudo element to define the background, and then on hover I simply scale the pseudo element. So far, so good...
    The problem is, I need some of the elements to stay inline with the scaled background, despite not scaling themselves. My original plan was to simply translate them, but I quickly realised that is not possible due to scale being based on multiples,
    and translate being based on percentage/pixels etc... The obvious solution is to scrap scale and instead use margin to shrink the absolutely positioned pseudo element. However, my reservation with this is that it is bad practice to transition the
    margin value. Can anybody think of a way in which I can use scale, and also maintain the alignment?</p>

  <div class="button">
    <div>Align Me</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work when you have padding on the parent, and you want the contents to stay in the same place. If you align the text to the left, you will see what I mean. This was my original solution. Thank you anyway :-D

Comment: @BenCarey, you did not mention that in your question, also you can see that `Hello World` stays in the same place. It means that your original solution works =))

Comment: It only works because the padding is not significant enough to touch the `h1` and the `transform-origin` is defaulted to the center. I didn't mention it because I mentioned 'without scaling the elements within the parent'. I should have been clearer

Comment: @BenCarey, thank you, I've updated my answer to reflect your requirements better.

Comment: I'll give you +1 because of your time and effort, however, I am not going to accept it as the solution as I specifically wanted to avoid scaling the elements within the parent as the children do not look great, they pixelate and move because of the scaling. In addition, it is the exact same solution as I originally coded (not that you knew that though) :-D

Comment: I am perfectionist when it comes to UI implementation, hence my dislike of 'reverse-scaling' haha

Comment: That was my last resort, transitioning the `margin` or `top, left, bottom, right` values as this is bad practice but I believe it is what I have to resort to doing...

Comment: @BenCarey, finally `transform` only solution. =))

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been out of the office. This is a very interesting update and I really appreciate the time you have put into this, however, it does not work well enough for me to use. Notice the gap between the button and the background as the background shrinks... I appreciate I didn't specify this in the question, but I was specifically looking for some sort of `calc` algorithm, as opposed to a dirty workaround if that makes sense? I will accept this as the answer as it 'technically' answers the question but I have ended up using `margin` as this yields the best result for the UX

Comment: @BenCarey, thank you for the update. Looks like the appearance is browser-dependent -- reverse-scaling works better in Blink and Webkit browsers, transform-only is better in Gecko. For some reason I do not believe that `calc` would do the trick. But I have one more idea =))

Answer (score 1):

If you are scaling by `p` then you are reducing the size and the new width will become `width*(1 - p)`. Same logic for the height. You can consider the use of `calc()` and easily define the translate using this formula.

*We divide by 2 because we reduce from both side and we will translate from 1 side*

```css
.tile {
  position: relative;
  width: 540px;
  height: 200px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.tile:hover:before {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
.tile:hover .button{
  transform: translate(calc(-540px*0.1/2),calc(200px*0.1/2));
}
.tile:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin:0;
}

.tile > .button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
  transition: transform .3s ;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <div class="button">Align Me</div>
</div>
```

You can consider CSS variables to easily change the scale value:

```css
.tile {
  position: relative;
  width: 540px;
  height: 200px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  --s:0.9;
}

.tile:hover:before {
  transform: scale(var(--s));
}
.tile:hover .button{
  transform: translate(calc(-540px*(1 - var(--s))/2),calc(200px*(1 - var(--s))/2));
}
.tile:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin:0;
}

.tile > .button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
  transition: transform .3s ;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <div class="button">Align Me</div>
</div>

<div class="tile" style="--s:0.5">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <div class="button">Align Me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very clever and exactly why I asked this question!!! I assume this will work if the parent has a width of `100%`?

Comment: @BenCarey the trap is there :) if it's width:100% then we need another trick. I will update for that case

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Also bear in mind that the height is dynamic based on the content... I only specified width and height for the example

Comment: @BenCarey chaging the HTML is an option?

Comment: Sure thing! The background doesn't have to be a psuedo element, I only did this because I didn't want to have `div class="_background">`. Change anything else you want :-D

Comment: @BenCarey you can then wrap the button inside a div and conisder that div like the pseudo element and scale it and then inside you unscale the button?

Comment: Are you saying that it isn't possible when you have a dynamic width/height?

Comment: @BenCarey no, I am wondering if this solution is ok for you: https://jsfiddle.net/y192aefb/

Comment: Unfortunately I was trying to avoid 'reverse-scaling' although I appreciate I didn't make this clear in my question. To be totally honest, I didn't think I would get an answer  as I was pretty confident this wasn't possible without transitioning `margin` but your code snippet above, despite not being suited to this particular solution, has taught me something so I really appreciate that!

Comment: @BenCarey is it only the margin the issue? or anything else than transform? because there is plenty of way to achieve this without margin

Comment: Hmmm, yes, I believe the margin is the only issue. I basically want to scale the background, whilst keeping the main content in parent in exactly the same position, aside from the button which needs to move with the background...

Comment: But just to be clear, I am aware that I can inverse/reverse the scaling on the elements within the parent. I want to avoid this at all costs. I would rather resort to transitioning the margin than doing this. The contents of the `div` on the site I am building is text and a figure (image). The code I posted above is just a simplified example.